# Java - Given Interface with methods - how are parameters passed?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, interface, concept

I tried to keep the code **as generic as possible**, this only represents 
the basic setup. I am a Java beginner trying to understand Interfaces, Classes 
and Methods. I did change the Interface name and Class names to make referencing
them easier. I am fully aware that **this code as it is won't compile**. 
I am trying to understand the concept.

Given is an Interface, with an existing InterfaceClass and another class
using the interface.

**Interface:**

```
public interface IInterface extends Comparable<IInterface>{    
    String getContent() throws DumbException;
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class InterfaceClass implements IInterface{
    public String getContent() throws DumbException {
        // here I would need a parameter (filepath) to get a file 
        // and read its content and return the content as string
        // however the interface doesn't provide a parameter for this
        // method. So how is this done?
    }
}
```

The class using the method:

```
public class Frame extends AbstractFrame {
    public void setDetails(IInterface details) {
        // This is the call I don't understand...
        details.getContent();     
    }
}
```

The part I don't understand is: 
How does the **details** object give any parameter to **getContent()**?
I mean I don't even see this object being defined other than **IInterface details**

Comment: `setDetails(IInterface details)` ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: I wish I could help I'm confused by your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

You can redefine `IInterface` to

```
public interface IInterface extends Comparable<IInterface>{    
    String getContent(String filepath) throws DumbException;
}

public class InterfaceClass implements IInterface{
    public String getContent(String filepath) throws DumbException {
        // use filepath to get the file's content
    }
}
```

Usage is

```
public class Frame extends AbstractFrame {
    public void setDetails(IInterface details) {
        details.getContent("/path/to/some/folder");     
    }
}
```

## Solution 2

You can't change `IInterface` but you add a constructor to `InterfaceClass`

```
public class InterfaceClass implements IInterface{
    private String filepath;

    public InterfaceClass(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    public String getContent() throws DumbException {
        // use filepath to get the file's content
    }
}
```

Usage is

```
new Frame().setDetails(new InterfaceClass("path/to/some/folder"));
```

Comment: Thank you for not only understanding my confused question but also for making it simple and clear!

Answer (score 0):

`details` is the argument passed to `setDetails` as type implementing `IInterface`. Anything that implements `IInterface` can be used as `details`, since the interface gives you contract assurance that `getContent` is in fact a strict member for that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a data in constructor in base class

```
public class InterfaceClass implements IInterface{

    private String data;

    public InterfaceClass(String data) {
        this.data = data;  
    }

    public String getContent() throws DumbException {
        //do something here with data

        // here I would need a parameter (filepath) to get a file 
        // and read its content and return the content as string
        // however the interface doesn't provide a parameter for this
        // method. So how is this done?
    }
}
```

You can use this class now:

```
IInterface myNewClass = new InterfaceClass("blablabla");
frameClass.setDetails(myNewClass);
```

And pass it to second class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public interface IInterface extends Comparable<IInterface>{

            String getContent() throws DumbException;
        }

    public class InterfaceClass implements IInterface{
        public String getContent() throws DumbException {//this method is of string type so you must provide return type 
            return "some details";
        }
    }

public class Frame extends AbstractFrame {
    public void setDetails(IInterface details) {
       System.out.println(details.getContent()); //output:- some details

    }
}

public class SomeClass{
public void someMethod(){
new Frame().setDetails(new InterfaceClass)
} 
}
```

Just pay note here to `SomeClass`. In `SomeClass` you are passing `object` of extended class i.e `interfaceClass` (and this is `ploymorphism`).

And like you did ,you need to pass object to `interface` variable like `IInterface details=new InterfaceClass()` or **some any other class that implements `IInterface but note that the class must extend that`IInterface`and in your case it is`interfaceClass`**

If you fail to that it will throw `nullpointerExecption` because it is just a reference variable , so you need to pass the object of actual class with that method and ploymorphism will handle rest.

**note** This is common way to access child classes and provides loose coupling and if you'll work on [spring](https://spring.io/) you'll know better.

Hope it helps